# How to convert only character variables to factor in R without dplyr?

Tags: r, dataframe

How can I convert only the character variables in a R data.frame to factor, without using the `dplyr` function `mutate_if`? I tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
df <- data.frame(w=c(1, 2, 3), x=c(4, 5, 6), y=c('7', '8', '9'), z=c('10', '11', '12'), stringsAsFactors = F)
str(df)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ w: num  1 2 3
 $ x: num  4 5 6
 $ y: chr  "7" "8" "9"
 $ z: chr  "10" "11" "12"

df[sapply(df, is.character)] <- sapply(df[sapply(df, is.character)], as.factor)
str(df)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ w: num  1 2 3
 $ x: num  4 5 6
 $ y: chr  "7" "8" "9"
 $ z: chr  "10" "11" "12"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is easier with `mutate_if`

```
df %>%
   mutate_if(is.character, factor)
```

In the OP's code, they used `sapply`, which converts to `matrix` and matrix can hold only a single class.  it is better to use `lapply`

```
i1 <- sapply(df, is.character)
df[i1] <- lapply(df[i1], factor)
```